# How can i add several audio tracks in moviepy to support different languages?

Tags: python, localization, video-processing, moviepy

Now i have a moviepy code that sets an audio to my CompositeVideoClip:

```
video = CompositeVideoClip([sequence])
video = video.set_audio(audio)
```

I would like to localize my video by adding additional soundtracks to it. Smth like this

```
video = CompositeVideoClip([sequence])
languages = ["en", "es", "it"]
for language in languages:
  # imagine i have localized_audios dict prepared
  soundtrack_name = language
  video = video.set_audio(localized_audios[language], soundtrack_name)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.